# Sorting data to align to specific rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I import student data for a testing software that uses a 4 digit student number. to export this data to my grading software I need to use their 9-10 digit student ID. I need to align their score with their 10 digit id. I don't need to get rid of the 4 digit number. Thinking I could set this up once and paste the columns C and D and then run some kid of sort function.

I could also just have it align the 4 digit number to a specific row number and that would work. Just don't know how to get started.

[image]

Comment: You may be able to do this with a `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: VLOOKUP could work.  But you'll need some sort of relationship that indicates which 4-digit ID goes with which 10-digit ID. Do you have that?

Comment: Yeah or the 4 digit code always goes to a specific row and I can paste the 10 digit number after. Just don't know how to set relationship

Comment: How do you know `54006726` goes with `1587`?

Comment: That was just an example each student has a permanent 4 digit code and a 9-10 digit code I just need to match them.  I could put students in alpha order (names also come with data) but when a student is absent  it would offset the list

Comment: The four digit and 10 digit numbers have nothing in common

Answer (score -2):

*This Reverse Lookup array formula help you to **align 10 digit ID's with 4 digit Student number**.*

[image]

```
{=IF(LENB2)>8,VLOOKUP(B11,CHOOSE({1,2},C2:C7,B2:B7),2,0),"")}
```

**NB:** Your ID's are 8 and 9 digits. So if you work with 9 and 10 then just replace >8 with >9.

Comment: Another very bad answer.  Please delete it.

Comment: Actually I'm waiting OP to react since he is the only person exactly describe his need :-). I've seen comments above, he was unable to create the bottom line of the question. And I think initially OP was looking for Student Nu to align with 10 digit ID. My perception was to pull IDs for Student's nu. Delete is ultimate option,,, :-)

Comment: Yes, which is exactly why you shouldn't have posted an answer - OP hasn't explained the question. Your answers had greatly improved, but this is an example of your previous style.  Worthless garbage.